# jQuery validator's addMethod does not support event object in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I've added custom validation on `input` type text and I am doing custom validation by checking event type:

```
$.validator.addMethod("customVal", function (value, element, options) {
   if (event.type == "blur" || event.type == "focusout" || event.type == 
      "keydown" || event.type == "click") {
       //custom logic
    }
}
```

This code works in Chrome, but on Firefox I am getting an error:

> Reference  error for event object.

I tried to add event in the parameter list like below:

`function(value, element, options, event)`

but this didn't work.

Comment: Can you add the code to a https://jsfiddle.net/ or https://codepen.io/ to illustrate the issue

Comment: There is no `event` parameter in the function of `$.validator.addMethod()`. What are you trying to achieve? The `if` shouldn't be required as the validation will occur for those events.

Comment: Actually, I don't want to execute my custom validation code on keyup event, because i am there i am calling external service, hence it increases the api call

Comment: You cannot decide what event will call the method inside the method itself, because by that time it's too late and the method will have been called already. You can do that inside the `validate()` function.

Answer (score 0):

There is no event parameter in the method of `$.validator.addMethod()`. You cannot decide what event will call the method inside the method itself, because by that time it's too late and the method will have been called already. You can do that inside the `validate()` function.

Let's say your form is `<form id="myForm">`, you can disable the validation on `onkeyup` event like this:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    onkeyup: false,
    //rules: {
    //},
    //messages: {
    //}
});
```

Comment: Will it disable the onkeyup event for all elements of the form?

Comment: Yes, the `validate()` method is called on the `form` itself as you can see, so it will apply to all its elements.

Comment: Ok, but i don't want to do it for all element

Comment: Then instead of `false`, use a function that checks for the event's target and decide whether to continue by returning `true` or not by returning `false`.